# Extract all rows with any value greater than x

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

Suppose I have a very large correlation table and only want to inspect the correlations greater than a certain value (e.g., 0.40). How can I extract all rows or columns that have some value greater than 0.40?

I can perform this operation using apply, but was hoping to perform the operation within the tidyverse.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- mtcars %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  cor() %>% 
  round(digits = 2) %>% 
  as.data.frame() 

df[apply(df, 1, function(row) {all(abs(row) > .40)}),]
```

Comment: @d.b I actually wanted to keep rows with "some" value greater than 0.40. Which can be down using any_vars() rather than all_vars().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `filter_all`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- mtcars %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  cor() %>% 
  round(digits = 2) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  filter_all(all_vars(abs(.) > 0.4))
```

**Result:**

```
    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
1  1.00 -0.85 -0.85 -0.78  0.68 -0.87  0.42  0.66  0.60  0.48 -0.55
2 -0.85  1.00  0.90  0.83 -0.70  0.78 -0.59 -0.81 -0.52 -0.49  0.53
```

To select *columns* where all values are greater than 0.4, use `select_if`:

```
df <- mtcars %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  cor() %>% 
  round(digits = 2) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  select_if(funs(all(abs(.) > 0.4)))
```

**Result:**

```
       mpg   cyl
mpg   1.00 -0.85
cyl  -0.85  1.00
disp -0.85  0.90
hp   -0.78  0.83
drat  0.68 -0.70
wt   -0.87  0.78
qsec  0.42 -0.59
vs    0.66 -0.81
am    0.60 -0.52
gear  0.48 -0.49
carb -0.55  0.53
```

**Note:**

If you want rows or columns with *any* value greater than 0.4, just switch out `all_vars` or `all` with `any_vars` or `any` respectively:

```
filter_all(any_vars(abs(.) > 0.4))

select_if(funs(any(abs(.) > 0.4)))
```

Comment: The original question asks for rows with *some* value greater than 0.4; for that you'd use `any_vars`.

Comment: @dash2 I do realize this, but my solution matches OP's output from `df[apply(df, 1, function(row) {all(abs(row) > .40)}),]`. So I guess he'll have to clarify which one he wants (accepting my answer kind of implied that he wanted `all_vars`). Either way, switching `all_vars` with `any_vars` is trivial

Answer (score 2):

In base R, you can use `rowSums` like this:

```
# get correlation matrix, values rounded to second digit
dat <- round(cor(mtcars[sapply(mtcars, is.numeric)]), 2)

# subset rows
dat[rowSums(abs(dat) > 0.4) == ncol(dat),]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
temp = cor(mtcars)
temp[rowSums(temp > 0.4) > 0, colSums(temp > 0.4) > 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the *tidy* way is to convert the correlation matrix to tidy format with `gather()`.

```
df1 <- mtcars %>% 
    select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
    cor() %>% 
    round(digits = 2) %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>%
    rownames_to_column %>%
    gather(colname, value, -rowname) %>%
    filter(abs(value) >= 0.4)
```

Note that this assumes you want *any* element of the matrix where the correlation is greater than 0.4.  If you want only the rows of the matrix where *all* elements of that row than 0.4, I guess you could do

```
df2 <- mtcars %>% 
    select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
    cor() %>% 
    round(digits = 2) %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>%
    rownames_to_column %>%
    gather(colname, value, -rowname) %>%
    group_by(rowname) %>%
    filter(min(abs(value)) >= 0.4)
```

The results are still in long (i.e. tidy) format.  It's arguable whether converting data that is naturally a matrix (e.g. a correlation matrix) to long format is good, but its generally true that everything in the tidyverse is easier if your data is in a tidy format.  So sometimes you have to force your data into an unnatural format to make (easy) use of the tidyverse.  It may not always be worth it.  In this particular case the I think the code is quite readable, moreso than anything in base R, but if your dataset is large performance may not be very good.

The result of `df2 %>% spread(colname, value)` is

```
  rowname am    carb  cyl   disp  drat  gear  hp    mpg   qsec  vs    wt   
1 cyl     -0.52  0.53  1.00  0.90 -0.70 -0.49  0.83 -0.85 -0.59 -0.81  0.78
2 mpg      0.60 -0.55 -0.85 -0.85  0.68  0.48 -0.78  1.00  0.42  0.66 -0.87
```